# Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке

Tags: php, javascript, html, submit

Есть сайт, на котором установлена платёжная система. Находясь на странице, где указана сумма, я нажимаю на кнопку "ок" (ниже приведён код) и я перехожу уже на сторону платёжной системы. Можно ли сделать так, что бы платёжная система открывалась в новой вкладке? В коде видно, что я пробовал `target="_blank"` , но без успешно. Помогите пожалуйста, если кто разберётся.

```
{if isset($m)}      

<div class="title-text">пополнение: WebMoney, QIWI, SMS, VISA, MASTERCARD, —бер Ѕанк, яндекс, CASH4WM, OKPAY, LiqPay, W1</span></div>       
<div class="blue-back">                
<div class="blue-back-center">         
<div class="block-text"> 

<p>{$lang['pay'][1]} <strong>{$oa}</strong>{$lang['pay'][2]} <strong>{$login},</strong> сразу после оплаты вам автоматически будет начислено игровой бонус</p>
<form id="fk" method="get"  action="http://www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php">    
<table align="center" border=0 width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="m" value="{$m}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="oa" value="{$oa}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="s" value="{$s}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="o" value="{$o}" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="javascript: document.getElementById('fk').submit()">
                                    <div class="form-buttons">
                                        <div class="b-gold">
                                            <div class="l"></div>
                                            <div class="c">
                                            <div class="b-t-type4">{$lang['ok_button']}</div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="r"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" value="Submit" />
                                    </div>
                      </a>
                                <br class="clearfloat" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

{else if !isset($system)}

<div class="title-text">пополнение: WebMoney, QIWI, SMS, VISA, MASTERCARD, —бер Ѕанк, яндекс, CASH4WM, OKPAY, LiqPay, W1</span></div>     
<div class="blue-back">                
<div class="blue-back-center">         
<div class="block-text">  

<form id= "fk" method="POST" action="?GE={$ge}&action=send&system=fk">
    <b>{$lang['pay']['sum']}: </b>
    <br class="clearfloat" />
    <br class="clearfloat" />
                  <div class="input-back">
                                        <div class="input-back-left-login"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-right"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-center">
                                            <input type="text" name="money" class="input-field"  value="150.00" ></td>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                  <a href="javascript: document.getElementById('fk').submit()">
                                    <div class="form-buttons">
                                        <div class="b-gold">
                                            <div class="l"></div>
                                            <div class="c">
                                            <div class="b-t-type4">{$lang['ok_button']}</div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="r"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" value="Submit" />
                                    </div>
                      </a>
                                <br class="clearfloat" />
</form>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>        
{/if}
```

Comment: эмм... а мне вот не видно в коде, что вы пробовали target="_blank"...

Comment: я его пробовал вставить в ссылки <a href="javascript: document.getElementById('fk').submit()">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target="_blank" надо указывать в `<form>`